# How do I send an AJAX request on a different port with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I need to send an AJAX request to, for example, port 8080 where a daemon is running there.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You cannot `POST` information cross domain, subdomain, or port number. You can however use JSONP if you have access to both the daemon *and* the requesting site. If data needs to be returned, then the `daemon` needs to support a `callback` query parameter and return it properly formatted.

Pass the information to the daemon:

```
$.getJSON('http://domain.com:8080/url/here?callback=?', {
  key: 'value',
  otherKey: 'otherValue'
}, function(data){
     // Handles the callback when the data returns
});
```

Now just make sure your daemon handles the `callback` parameter. For instance, if `callback=mycallback` the return from the daemon (the only thing written to the page) should look like this:

For an key/value pairs:

```
mycallback( {'returnkey':'returnvalue', 'other':'data' });
```

For an array:

```
mycallback( [1,2,3] );
```

If you do not have a JSONP or similar mechanism in place, you cannot communicate cross domain using jQuery.

Comment: Is there a general way to replace `domain.com`?This way it can only work in production,because I use `localhost` in developing environment.

Comment: You should be able to use `'http://' + window.location.hostname + ':8080/url'` to build the URL that will work both locally and online.

Answer (score 43):

This breaks the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). You cannot use a different port, even when using the same domain.

You can use JSONP as [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-to-send-request-to-non-80-port-on-the-same-site-with-jquery/2099771#2099771) suggested.

Or else, as another possible workaround, you could set up a very simple [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) (using [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) if you are on Apache). This would allow you to use relative paths in your AJAX request, while the HTTP server would be acting as a proxy to any "remote" location.

The fundamental configuration directive to set up a reverse proxy in [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) is the ProxyPass. You would typically use it as follows:

```
ProxyPass     /ajax/     http://www.localhost:8080/
```

In this case, you would request `/ajax/test.xml` with jQuery, but in fact the server would serve this by acting as a proxy to `http://www.localhost:8080/test.xml` internally.

If you are using IIS, you may want to use the [Managed Fusion URL Rewriter and Reverse Proxy](http://www.codeplex.com/Wikipage?ProjectName=urlrewriter) to set up a reverse proxy.

Comment: +1 For a fantastic answer. I answered the wrote "blah blah blah" canned response, and you provided a very viable solution. Thanks Daniel!

Comment: Oh,proxy will cause extra processing on server side.So I'll choose jsonP

Comment: I'd been scratching around for day trying to work out why I couldn't post data across ports before I found this. Thanks man.

Comment: hey, what about CORS?

Answer (score 2):

This counts as a different origin, even though you have it on the same box, just different port.

If you are targetting mostly new browsers like FireFox 3.5 and up, you can try to add `Access-Control` headers to your application in another port and allow to call from your default app pool. Information about access control headers can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control

IE also implements it (again, in using a different ACTIVEX control, why so?): http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/01/14/completing-access-control-support-for-xdomainrequest.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(VS.85).aspx