# Understanding cross domain difference for AJAX POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have written a piece of jQuery code in http://example.com.

The code looks like this:

```
$.post('http://example.com:3000/service',params,function(data){});
```

This code **works** in chrome and firefox but **not in IE**. Is my request crossbrowser?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your calling page is on port 80, it'll be a x-browser request. Scheme, domain and port are all taken into account.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery

Comment: eh, who needs to know the specifics about the error, right? the important thing is that it works in some situation, and it doesnt in others. :\

Answer (score 0):

[JSONP with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681466/jsonp-with-jquery)

I think you're looking for JSONP - check that link for an example