# I cannot get any reult using $.ajax() here, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, glassfish

Using a **GlassFish** server running on port 8080, I can access `http://localhost:8080/ws/` through my web browser.

But the webpage cannot be fetched using `jQuery`, `$.ajax` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/ws/",
    type: "GET",
    success: function() {alert("good");},
    error: function() {alert("error");}
});
```

Every time, a message box with "error" is shown.

Here is what I captured using firebug:

[image]

But the response tag shows nothing:

[image]

Can anyone give me any suggestion about how to debug this?

**NOTE:**

1. I have try to use `error: function(request, status, error)`, but nothing useful is fetched.
2. Using Wireshark to capture loopback HTTP packets, I can see that all the response is there, but not shown by firebug as illustrated above.

Comment: Is the web site doing the request also at localhost:8080?

Comment: What do you want achive with your source code? Normally Ajax is used to send data. I cannot see that.

Comment: No, that site is a localhost:80, @Juhana

Comment: Yes, I use that ajax code to send data, but it doesn't work. So I try to simplify it to a minimal set of code to see what's wrong. @reporter

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send an AJAX request on a different port with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've said that the page you're running your jQuery code on is from *"`localhost:80`"*, so that means you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents cross-origin ajax calls. Port 80 and port 8080 are different origins for the purpose of the SOP.

Just for completeness, here's a list of what must be the same for two origins to match:

- The protocol (so, `file:` vs. `http:` vs. `https:`, etc.)
- The port
- The server name (e.g., `localhost`, `example.com` vs. `sub.example.com`, etc.)

The origin is matched against the *document* (the HTML file containing the script tag), not the location of the script file itself.

Comment: Then why we can access RESTful apis provided by Google using Javascript?

Comment: @UniMouS: If you're doing that via ajax, Google's servers must be using [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) (and your browser must support it).