# AJAX call through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I've a problem with an AJAX GET call using jQuery.

Here's my code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    

    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:8080/aplus-framework-webapp/reportServlet?",
        data: "STAT_START_DATE=20131001&STAT_END_DATE=20131031&CAMPAIGN_START_DATE=2013-10-31&CAMPAIGN_END_DATE=2013-10-01&ORDER=Stato",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        processdata: true, 
        success : function (data) {
            alert("IN");
        },
        error : function (richiesta,stato,errori) {
            alert("NOT SUCCESS");    
        }
    });// end ajax call
}); // end ready
</script>
```

The servlet reportServlet is my Java servlet running in localhost that return a JSON:

```
{"url":"http://d1p0y6pjyasam8.cloudfront.net/PGBANNER/text/20131105100823campaigns.csv"}
```

I test the page in local but I always see the alert reporting 'NOT SUCCESS'.

I'm new to JS, anyone have any idea on which could be my mistake?

Thanks

Alessio

Comment: what is the url of your test page

Comment: @user your json gives error on validation: Parse error on line 1:
"Nome";""Ragione soc
^
Expecting '{', '[' please fix it and tell us if it works later

Comment: http://localhost:8080/aplus-framework-webapp/reportServlet , check whether this URL works , remove the ? from the URL , and try to Lert error in the failure block

Comment: Instead of just printing `NOT SUCCESS`, print the actual error. The API gives this to you in the `error` callback! You have called it `errori`, so print that.

Comment: I modify my Java servlet adding in the response header:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Now I can see the alert 'IN' and the json that my servlet return.

Comment: @user917651 did you validate json?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I send an AJAX request on a different port with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are Sure Your servlet return header json ?

Comment: I modify my Java servlet adding in the response header:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Now I can see the alert 'IN' and the json that my servlet return.

Comment: I specify the conten type of the response in my header but i didn't specify the param: Access-Control-Allow-Origin. So my header was wrong we can say. Thanks!

Comment: So did removing the question mark actually solve the problem?

Comment: No, it's nothing to do with headers. The AJAX request was violating the [`Same-origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which was fixed by configuring the server to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Answer (score 1):

If the website you're requesting from and the servlet you're requesting on do not have the same port (for instance 80 and 8080), it will break the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

[See this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery) form more information and answers.

Comment: I modify my Java servlet adding in the response header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* Now I can see the alert 'IN' and the json that my servlet return

Comment: `+1` - this is the correct answer, since the OP reconfigured the server to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the question mark at the end of your url

Comment: Nothing to do. I remove the question mark but the result is the same Maurice.

Comment: I modify my Java servlet adding in the response header:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Now I can see the alert 'IN' and the json that my servlet return.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean with 'page in local' that you try this in a local file on your hard-drive. This is disabled due to security reasons in mainly all browsers. You can find further information how to disable this in Google Chrome for development purposes here:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2010/11/29/disabling-cross-domain-security-check-for-ajax-development-in-google-chrome/

Comment: I modify my Java servlet adding in the response header:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*

Now I can see the alert 'IN' and the json that my servlet return.