# Including php page in html page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cross-domain

Here I'm trying to access some php page in html page. Both running on different servers one is on WAMP server and I can see the page in browser when I hit

```
http://localhost:8080/winnersphp/index.php
```

Now I'm trying to access that page in ajax load like in another html page running in different server (in Eclipse , which is jetty server (java)) in localhost and the page URL is

```
http://localhost:8888/includephp.html
```

and in this html page I'm using Jquery

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#externalHeader").load("http://localhost:8080/winnersphp/index.php");
    });
</script>
```

But no luck. Is there any security issues ?? or domain issues ??

Initially I thought about some domain issue, but both running on localhost. Port causing any problem here ?

Can some one point me what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @NateKibler Just cross checked. Nothing. No errors. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like jQuery's `.load()` method is similar to the `.get()` function, which is subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This does, indeed, restrict against different port numbers.

If you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), though, you can still accomplish your task by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099771/2482557