# Change Python Post Request to Ajax Post Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

I want to change this code in python to $.post of jQuery

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import httplib, urllib, json

words = u'Hello'
request = {
    'api_key': 'YOUR API KEY',
    'params': [words]
}
params = json.dumps(request)

headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept": "application/json"}

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("abc.com:3000")
conn.request("POST", "/service/rest/", params, headers)

response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
conn.close()
print data
```

Like This

```
$.post("abc.com:3000/service/rest/", );
```

Thank for Help. I have never learned Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
var words = ['Hello']

$.post("abc.com:3000/service/rest/",
    JSON.stringify({
        'api_key': 'YOUR API KEY',
        'params' : words
    }), function(response){
        console.log(response)
    }
)
```

`console.log(response)` should display the response from the server in the JS console.

**Note:** This will not work across domains or subdomains due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) for Javascript. If this applies to you, you might want to take a look at [JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery)