# Calling localhost from developer console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, devtools

Is there any way to call a server active on a port on localhost from developer console on chrome/firefox/safari? I'd like to run a script in the developer console while contacting a server on localhost.

Comment: So do you want to open `siteA:portA` and send a request to `siteB:portB` from opened console on `siteA`, correct?

Comment: @extempl Not just siteB but localhost. When I tried to do localhost it instead send a request to siteA.

Comment: I see, so you definitely need the different port. Then you should consider creating the local server which will route different domains to different ports, so then you'll be able to do requests between them, as ajax implementation won't let you do cross-port requests

Comment: See the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery

Comment: @extempl Ok thanks.