# How can I access a local hug API using JavaScript?

Tags: python, jquery, json, hug

I have an Apache2 web server as well as a Python hug server running. Both run on different ports. I now want to sent a request to the hug server using jQuery. As this is cross domain, I think I have to use something similar to this: [How do I send an AJAX request on a different port with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099728/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-on-a-different-port-with-jquery) 
jsonp with callback parameter.

My questions is:
 - is my approach reasonable?
 - does hug support jsonp with callback?
 - could there be a better solution to communicate between javascript and the Python hug API?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to send a `GET` request on your API you can use the jQuery method:

```
$.getJSON(your_url, function(json_received){
      console.log(json_received);
    });
```

If you need to send data trough a `POST` request you need to add more parameters in ajax method :

```
    $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          url: your_url,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: JSON.stringify({'message':'your_message}),           
          success: function(data_received) {
            console.log(data_received);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
      });
```

In the API response you need to add the parameter `{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}` to allow cross domain.

Comment: thanks for the quick response! Does this work between different ports as well?

Comment: Yes you can specify the port in `your_url`. For instance `http://127.0.0.1:5000` if it's a localhost on the 5000 port.