# Rest api returns error 403 while calling from Wordpress but works in postman

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-403, wordpress-rest-api, ajaxform

I have one server on which Apache and Tomcat both are installed to run my **Wordpress** and **Java application** respectively. Both are on same ip address and using same domain `https://www.example.com` only port number is different.

Wordpress is running on default port while Tomcat is runing on 8443.
A rest api on Tomcat `https://www.example.com:8443/myApi.html` is working fine from postman, but when calling from wordpress using ajax, it returns error 403 forbidden response.

I am stuck on searching its solution but failed.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use a different port, even when using the same domain. This breaks the Same origin policy.You can however use JSONP if you have access to both the daemon and the requesting site. If data needs to be returned, then the daemon needs to support a callback query parameter and return it properly formatted.

please see  1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099771

2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2099784

Comment: The main contribution of this answer appears to be links to other SO posts, for which a comment (or close as duplicate) is more appropriate. If a combination of the information from both referenced posts is necessary to answer the OP's question, then please expand your answer.